# How do I force a FloatLayout to keep the same dimensions as the image inside it when window size changes using Kivy?

Tags: kivy

I have an image of a chessboard added to a FloatLayout. The chessboard resizes just fine, but the layout always shows beyond the borders of the chessboard image. The background of the FloatLayout is green so I can see it.

The app opens with window maximized & no matter how I adjust the layout with size_hint when I restore the window to default size (not maximized) some part of the layout is showing.

Is there a way to make the layout always be the same size as the image inside it when it auto-resizes when the window is resized manually with the mouse or by the maximize button?

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)
Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'maximized')
Config.write()

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

kivy.require('2.0.0')

class DraggableArea(FloatLayout):  # FloatLayout
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DraggableArea, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (.547, .89)
        self.layout_size_not_retrieved = True
        self.initial_updated_layout_size = None

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0, 1, 0, 1) 
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=(200, 200),
                                  pos=(300, 200))
        def update_rect(instance, value):
            instance.rect.pos = instance.pos
            instance.rect.size = instance.size
            if self.layout_size_not_retrieved:
                if self.rect.size[0] > 100:
                    self.initial_updated_layout_size = self.rect.size
                    self.add_widget(
                        Image(source="./data/images/chess-pieces/DarkerGreenGreyChessBoard.png", pos=self.rect.pos,
                              size_hint=(1, 1), keep_ratio=True, allow_stretch=True))
                    self.add_widget(
                        MoveableImage(source="./data/images/chess-pieces/WhiteQueen57.png",
                                      pos=self.rect.pos))
                    self.layout_size_not_retrieved = False

        self.bind(pos=update_rect, size=update_rect)


class MoveableImage(DragBehavior, Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MoveableImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.drag_timeout = 10000000
        self.drag_distance = 0
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]
        self.size_hint = (.1, .1) 
        self.keep_ratio = True
        self.allow_stretch = True  

    def on_pos(self, *args):
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]


class egGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        c = DraggableArea()
        c.pos = (40, 40)

        return c


if __name__ == '__main__':
    egGameApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're giving two set of contradictory instructions to DraggableArea, it cannot obey the instruction to maintain it size relative to the window size while also instructed to maintain it size relative it inner child
Either you set the aspect ratio to False by setting `keep_ratio=False`, or scale the image relative to the window size while maintain the image aspect ratio and then set the DraggableArea size relative to the image texture. If you're going for the later approach the you might also want to reset the position of DraggableArea to `pos_hint` to `center_y: 0.5` to vertically center it.

Comment: Peter A.  --Ok, so how do I "set the DraggableArea size relative to the image texture"?